# How to close Window Media Player after it is finish playing?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know how to close the media player when it finishes playing my wav file. Because if I run this multiple times, it consumes an dangerous amount of computer ram. If you can solve that without closing it, by all means tell me.

```
var player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
player.URL = @"D:\notes\01.wav";
```

This is the code to play it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to exit the player, the only(not so ideal approach) is to kill it.

```
    var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("wmplayer");
    if (proc.Length > 0) {
        proc[proc.Length - 1].Kill();
    }
```

Comment: sure, if you would be so kind, care to explain the meaning behind proc.length > 0? and proc.length - 1?

Comment: First, `proc.Length > 0` means that there are processes with "wmplayer" second, with `proc[proc.Length - 1]` you kill the last one of them in the processlist.

Comment: So if I'm getting it right, var proc you created made an array that figured out how many wmplayer are playing?

Comment: Correct, and since you just added a new one while playing you have to kill the last one added.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
var player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
player.URL = @"D:\notes\01.wav";
Thread.Sleep(2000);
player.controls.stop();
player.close();
```

**Edit**

Than you can kill the process and stop the WMPlayer

```
var prc = Process.GetProcessesByName("wmplayer");
if (prc.Length > 0) prc[prc.Length - 1].Kill();
```

Comment: I tried that before but it doesn't play the sound now. I also can't have it pause because I want to have it run as if a background sound and not stopping me from doing other functions.